# Posting to controller gives 404 error - routing seems to be broken?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a very simple controller + action, and when I do a POST I get a 404 I simply doesn't understand.

**My RouteConfig:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Task view",
                url: "task/{projectid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Task", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

}
```

**My controller:**

```
public class TaskController : Controller
{


    // GET: Task
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int projectid)
    {
       // extremely nice and insightful code
        return View(vm);
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateSigneeRequest([FromBody] TaskViewModel task)
    {
        // even more smart code
        return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

}

Now, I can easily open `/task/75` and I get the correct Index result and have a project ID. But I simply cannot POST to `/task/UpdateSigneeRequest` . I have also tried removing the parameter from this method but nothing seems to work.

I simply don't understand this as my `Default` route should match this (Controller being task, action being UpdateSigneeRequest , id being optional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a constraint for your route definition so that it is specific for a **number** value after `task` in the url and your GET request will be properly handled (ex : `/task/100`) by that definition.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Task view",
    url: "task/{projectid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Task", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { projectid = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can do the same thing (specifying a constraint for your parameter) in [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) as well.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("Task/{projectid:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int projectid)
{
     return View(new SomeViewModel { ProjectId =  projectid});
}
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateSigneeRequest(IndexVm task)
{
    return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```